# Why does Eddie Temple say that XXXX's life and Charlotte's are inextricably linked?

Tags: plot-explanation, layer-cake

I'm struggling to come to grips with how much Jimmy planned in advance in *Layer Cake*. My understanding so far is that Jimmy's plan was to use XXXX to find Charlotte, then take his money away using Mr. Singh, then put him in prison for cocaine possession.

But this doesn't explain why he used XXXX to find Charlotte, or is what he said about private investigators at the start being ex-policemen actually why he wanted to use XXXX?